# Find complement of number in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find the complement of a number in Python. I know there are other solutions but I am trying to make my own.
My first try:

```
def findComplement(self, num):
    """
    :type num: int
    :rtype: int
    """
    numb = str(num)
    i = 0
    while(i<=len(numb)):
        if numb[i] == "0":
            numb[i] = "1"
        else:
            numb[i] = "0"
        i=i+1
    return int(numb)
```

But strings are immutable so it gave an error,
My second try:

```
def findComplement(self, num):
    """
    :type num: int
    :rtype: int
    """
    numb = str(num)
    numb2 = []
    k =0
    for j in numb:
        numb2[k] = j #error on this line
        k=k+1
    i = 0
    while(i<=len(numb2)):
        if numb2[i] == "0":
            numb2[i] = "1"
        else:
            numb2[i] = "0"
        i=i+1
    return int(numb2)
```

Error in program 2:

```
Line 11: IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: Do you mean complement in the complex number sense? Define complement please. Your error is because `numb2 = []` when you try to access index 0 - which doesn't exist. Did you mean `numb2.append(j)`?

Comment: Do you mean "one's complement" or "two's complement" or "bit complement" (which is the same as one's complement) or "logical complement" or some other kind of complement?

Answer (score 3):

Since other answers cover your main problem, you can also just use a dictionary for mapping `1` to `0`, and vice versa:

```
>>> d = {'0': '1', '1': '0'}
>>> s = '0101'
>>> ''.join(d[x] for x in s)
'1010'
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have to find complement of `101` if we xor the input with the mask `111` then we will get `010` which is complement.

```py
def findComplement(self, num: int) -> int:
        mask_len=len(bin(num))-2
        mask=int("1"*mask_len,2)
        return mask^num
```

Answer (score 1):

So I wanted find the binary complement of a number myself
but was unstatisfied with how the mask is generated and other things, cause they involved using the string representation of the binray number.

So I dug a little deeper and came across this [reddit post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70246943/python-xor-of-all-the-bits-of-an-integer)
where they generated the mask via bitwise shifts.

And I also found out that you can get the bit count of an integer
with `int.bit_lenght(<your_number>)`,
instead of using `len(bin(<your-number>)[2:])`.
Only problem is: that it returns 0 for the number 0.
So you have to account for that.

Tho I have no clue what method is more performant
and whether it is worth it compared to string manipulation.

But in the end that was my final solution
that I found was pretty neat cause it doesn't involve strings.

```py
def bin_complement(num, on_two=False, bit_count=0):
    """
    num(int) dezimal number
    on_two(bool) complement on 2 else on 1
    bit_count = number of bits for the mask, defaults to bits in num
    returns(int) complementary number
    """
    bit_count = max(bit_count, num.bit_length(), 1)
    mask = 2 ** bit_count - 1
    complement = num ^ mask
    if on_two:
        complement += 1
    return complement
```

Edit: `2**bit_count - 1` is a faster way for doing

```py
for _ in range(bit_count):
    mask <<= 1
    mask |= 1
```

Edit2: If you want to take the complement of fixed length bit number.

E.G: C_1(0001) -> 0001 xor 1111 = 1110
and not just 0000.

You can now set a bit_count value for the mask
so the complement works correct.

Answer (score 0):

`numb2` is an empty list. It does not have any elements to be addressed (and updated). What you need is a `bytearray`, rather than a `list`  (or a `string`):

```
def findComplement(self, num):
    """
    :type num: int
    :rtype: int
    """
    numb = bytearray(str(num), 'utf-8')
    i = 0
    while(i<len(numb)):
        if numb[i] == ord("0"):
            numb[i] = ord("1")
        else:
            numb[i] = ord("0")
        i=i+1
    return int(numb)
```

As can be seen, this requires some minor other changes, as the stored data in a `bytearray` is a byte (0-255) rather than a char. The solution is to use the `ord` function, to get the byte number from `"0"` and `"1"`. In addition there is a small issue (off by one) in your `while`expression. Since the indexing and your count start at zero `i` should be strictly smaller than the length of the string.

I would also like to add that there are simper ways to achive the complement of 0 and/or 1, though.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems.

First you are not converting your input to a binary string properly. This can be done by `numb = bin(num)[2:]` instead of `num = str(num)`.

Second, you are trying to index into your empty `numb2` list. Actually there is no need to create a separate `numb2` list, you can just operate directly on your `numb` string, as in your first attempt. For example:

```
for i in range(len(numb)):
    if numb[i] == "0":
        numb[i] = "1"
    else:
        numb[i] = "0"
```

Finally, to convert your binary string back to an int you should do `int(numb, 2)` not `int(numb)`.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a one-liner, here is one:

```py
int(bin(value)[2:].zfill(numbits).translate(str.maketrans('01', '10')), 2)
```

The above computes a `numbits`-bit ones' complement for `value`.
Since `str.maketrans('01', '10')` is a constant (dictionary), one can compute it ahead of time:

```py
dMatrix = str.maketrans('01', '10') # which is {48: 49, 49: 48}
int(bin(value)[2:].zfill(numbits).translate(dMatrix), 2)
```

Converting this one-liner to a function is straightforward:

```py
def onescomplement(value, numbits):
    return int(bin(value)[2:].zfill(numbits).translate(str.maketrans('01', '10')), 2)
```

HTH

Answer (score -2):

Don't you just mean the ~ operator, e.g:

```
def findComplement(self, num):
    return ~num
```