# Is there a relation between these two operations?

Tags: twos-complement

I've noticed that when converting to and from 2's complement, we can either add or subtract one, depending on when we perform the bitwise complement.

i.e., let P be an integer, to represent -P we could use 2's complement representation. let this representation be Q.
To write -P, we first invert all bits and then add 1.

But to convert back, we could ...

- subtract 1 and then invert
- invert and add 1

I couldn't understand why these two work to produce an equivalent result.

*Example:*
To represent -17  (17 is *0001 0001*)  (-17 in 2's complement is *1110 1111*)

invert(1110 1111) = 0001 0000 and then 0001 0000 + 1 = 0001 0001
1110 1111 - 1 = 1110 1110 and then invert(1110 1110) = 0001 0001

Comment: Did you try to prove it?

Comment: It's like this: take one step back and then turn around, or turn around and then take one step forward.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain -P:

- Flip the bits in P
- Add 1 to this

---

We now take the inverse of it

(Reverse the order, and take the inverse of each operation):

- Inverse of flipping the bits is flipping the bits once again
- Inverse of adding one is subtracting one.

From this, we can understand that the inverse of this method is:

- Subtract 1 from -P
- Flip the bits in this

You can see that this is the first method

---

The second method is basically -(-P), which evaluates to P. You are essentially repeating the two's complement process again:

- Flip the bits in -P
- Add 1 to this

Comment: Can we say that if Q is the 2's complement representation of -P, then P is the 2's complement representation of -Q?

Comment: @rohitt Yes, You can!

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer yes there is relation.

The simple complement is the "inverse" of a binary number.
That can be achieved by xoring every bit in its binary reprentation
for a given bit size.
(including the trailing ones!)

A python implementation for the complement and twos complement
can be found at [this reddit question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70296474/11433019).

Now we can show you can reverse all of the steps for a fixed length binary number.

E.g: 8 bit number 17

```py
number = 17
#0b10001
print(bin(number))

comp = bin_complement(number, bit_count=8)
#0b11101110
print(bin(comp))

twos_comp = comp+1
#0b11101111
print(bin(twos_comp))

twos_comp_min_one = twos_comp-1

reversed_num = bin_complement(twos_comp_min_one, bit_count=8)
#0b10001 -> 17
print(bin(reversed_num))
```