# Python XOR of all the bits of an integer

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

I would like to know if an integer's binary representation has an odd number of bits equal to one.

There is a trivial solution by manipulating bytes and using a few shifts but I think that it is more costly than using a XOR of every bits.

Is there a way to manipulate bits directly instead of bytes ?

Comment: this might help you: https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/bitwise_XOR.html#example-1

Comment: You could simply use `bool(bin(my_int).count('1') % 2)`.

Comment: You should *measure* to see if it's actually more costly.

Comment: You should also consider an appropriate data structure (e.g., https://pypi.org/project/bitarray/) rather than using an `int`.

Comment: Indeed a bit array seems better. I will measure to see if it's more costly to use this solution (`bool(bin(my_int).count('1') % 2)`).
I don't want to use a XOR with shifts because for an array of 128 bitsI would have to do 128 shifts and XOR the output with 1 128 times. In the end, it computes 128*128 XOR when it could be done with only 128 XOR

Answer (score 2):

int type is unbounded in python so this could be one way:

```
number = 34
i = 0
for n in bin(number):
    if n == '1':
        i += 1
if i % 2 == 0:
    print('even')
else:
    print('odd')
```

I wanted to try an alternative for not having to use strings.

```
number = 4
mask = 1 << (int.bit_length(number) - 1) if number > 0 else 0
ones = 0
while mask  > 0:
    if number & mask > 0:
        ones += 1
    mask >>= 1
if bool(ones % 2):
    print('odd')
else:
    print('even')
```

Just a comment: I had to handle the exception in case the number has the value 0 because, in this case, the 'bit_length' method of the 'int' class returns 0.

```
mask = 1 << (int.bit_length(number) - 1) if number > 0 else 0
```

I disagree because at least one bit is needed to represent the value 0 . After that it can be turned on or off but at least one is required. For example the 'bin' function with parameter 0 returns '0b0' and not '0b' or ''.

```
>>> bin(0)
'0b0'
```

I think int.bit_length(0) should return 1. Pyton tooltip tells: "Number of bits necessary to represent self in binary".